# Error viewing pages/ in wagtail CMS

Tags: django, wagtail

I started getting an error when viewing pages in wagtail cms:

```
ProgrammingError at /cms/pages/
column "wagtailcore_page.content_type_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "wagtailcore_page"."id", "wagtailcore_page"."content_...
```

Viewing the Root CMS page seems to be fine and also editing pages. If i access a child page such as `/cms/pages/6/` that works but if i view the parent `/cms/pages/5/` it causes the error.

Any ideas how this is happening?

```
wagtail==1.13.1
Django==1.10.5
```

The page class looks like:

```
class LandingPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('rich_text', RichTextBlock()),
        #('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ('image_grid', ImageGridBlock()),
        ('two_columns', TwoColumnBlock()),
        ('landing_map', MapBlock()),
        ('video_grid', VideoGridBlock()),
        ('slider', SliderBlock()),
        ('steps', StepsBlock()),
        ('pricing', PricingBlock()),
        ('centered', RichTextBlock(template='blocks/centered.html')),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

**Update:**

If I add a query string `?ordering=title` to the URL it works, it seems there is an issue with the annotate operation in the index view that is causing this, strange thing is, it was working ok before and it works with the same codebase on my staging server so I don't understand how this just started.

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace of the error, please?

Comment: @gasman here is the [traceback](https://gist.github.com/dantium/75d6d3b41a8b141c7b24e0988f664792)

Comment: It would really help to see the full query that's breaking. Is the snippet shown really all you get in the error message? Any way to click to expand it, perhaps...?

Comment: @gasman This started working again after I made a new DB, something must have gone wrong with the DB when I cloned it from the server to cause this error. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Discovered issue was related to data/structure in Postgres DB that had been cloned from a working server. Working from a clean DB resolved the issue.